# My laptop thinks its screen resolution is 1280x800, but it's actually 1366x768. The bottom of the screen is cropped

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution

Windows does not even list the 1366x768 screen resolution, and it's not a driver issue because the BIOS boot screen is showing cropped and shifted to the left.

What can I do? I just turned on my laptop and this happened, and I have no idea what to do now. It's a Toshiba Satellite L755, and nothing like this has ever happened to it before.

Comment: Has it always been like this or is it a recent thing?

Comment: It worked correctly until just now. When I turned it on, the BIOS boot screen was cropped and so is everything else. It seems the laptop thinks its resolution is different than it is.

Comment: Does one of your Fn keys allow you to change your display aspect ratio?

Comment: The [manual](http://forums.toshiba.com/tshb/attachments/tshb/brd_recovery/16436/1/L750UsersManual.pdf) suggests `Fn` + `F5`.

Answer (score 0):

That is really odd if its doing it in the BIOS. I'd suggest doing WHAT @Burgi says. Else a dumb old trick might work: remove the battery & power cord, press & hold the power button for 30sec, then re-insert/connect & see if its still acting up